# PHP, MySQL E-Commerce Filtering Approach

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a quick question in regards to the approach to displaying products on an e-commerce package I am putting together. The problem that I facing is that I would like visitors of the site narrow their search.

For example, a use case would be:

1. A Visitor is currently browsing a season of products (eg. Summer Collections)
2. He / She should then be able to filter by category and brand within that season, so for example they might decide that they only want to see Pants from Clothes Galore.

The problem, I ma facing is that doing a single SQL query in order to find products that match all three of these factors (so the product is in the summer collection, is a pair of pants and made by clothes galore). The thing that makes this overly difficult is that products can be in multiple categories and seasons. So there would need to be an insane amount joins in order to grab the right result.

My database structure is as follows:

```
product -> product_category <- category
product -> product_season <- season
product <- brand (a product can only be made by one brand)
```

Hope someone can share their wisdom on this...

Comment: Your table structure is vary vague.  If product_season and product_category are already parts of the product table, why would you need to join at all?  I'm assuming they are sharing a category_id and season_id or something.  I'll write an answer under that assumption.

Comment: Hey sorry that was suppose to be a sketchy ERD. The product_category and product_season represent bridging entities between the product and the respective joining table (eg. category or season). Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I'm assuming they are fields in both tables that are the same?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Worked for me.  You get a sketch of solution from sketch of ERD :).

Comment: the product table gives the respective bridging table its primary id and the respective table gives its primary id in order to create the many to many relationship. So aggregation might be the best solution here because Active Record is not very good for building complex join queries like the one I need to do these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a big catalog, you might be better to use Apache Solr ( http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ ).  Otherwise, there are a few approaches.

You don't need the overhead and straight SQL isn't that insane, will perform reasonably well:

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_category
LEFT JOIN category
LEFT JOIN product_season
LEFT JOIN season
WHERE season = ? AND category = ?
```

Alternatively, If you don't like the number of rows returned, you can aggregate the category and season into the product table (new columns), then use like queries to find things:

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product
where product.categories like '% category %'
  and product.seasons like '% season %'
```

Comment: This is a bit more like what I was looking for ... I am afraid because I am using Active Record as my query building mechanism multiple joins as per your first suggestion are difficult. The aggregation idea however would be best as it provides a quick lookup index when searching through products.

Comment: Make sure you index your fields properly in your DBMS.

Comment: ok ... all my primary keys are indexed. And the product name which is the only column that any searching against. And then obviously the aggregate columns that you were suggesting. Is that correct?

Answer (score -1):

```
Select product.* From product 
  Left Join product_category On (product.product_id = product_category.product_id)
  Left Join product_season On (product.product_id= product_season.product_id)
  Left Join brand On (product.product_id = brand.product_id)
    Where product_category.category_id = '$catId'
    And product_season.season_id = '$seasonId'
    And brand.brand_id = '$brandId'
      Order By product.product_name
```

Ok, this is assuming `product`, `product_category`, `product_season`, `brand`, `season`, `category` are all tables.  You should pass in the ID's of the `season` and `category` table directly from whatever you are using to filter the search by so that you don't have to join these tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I have been considering this approach but the fact that I am using Active Record in order to build my queries makes this not very maintainable for me. I have to add pagination and ordering on the fly as well and I don't want to end up concatenating strings together all over the place to build the query.